# Simple product of a list function in python?

Tags: python-3.x

tried searching, but I can't seem to get this right.. could someone help me out?

I just need to make a simple function to this effect:

```
def productoflist(*x):
  return product(x)
```

I made a function for the sum of a list this way with sum(), but I know there isn't a product function built into python and I need to do it without any other modules.

What's the simplest way to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect the outcome is for `[1,2,3,4]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
def productoflist(l):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, l, 1)

>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> productoflist(l)
24
```